# jQuery slideToggle on Internet Explorer 7

Tags: jquery, css

Made a simple script that hide/show a hidden div. The page automatically adjusts its height on Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

However on Internet Explorer 7, the div overlaps the contents at the bottom I'm currently using Joomla as CMS. Where have i gone wrong ? I have tried including "position:relative" for the bottom contents but it isn't helping.

```
$j(idName).css({"opacity": "0"});
$j(idName).slideToggle('fast', function() { 
    $j(idName).animate({opacity:"1"}, function() {
        if(jQuery.browser.msie) {
            this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
            $j("#main-body").css("height","auto");
        }
    }); 

});
```

Visit http://educationtechnologysummit.com/sponsors-a-partners.html with IE 7 to get a clearer view. Click on Read more for Amazone

Comment: Instead of browser detection (which is incorrect in IE9), use feature detection, change `if(jQuery.browser.msie) {` for `if(!jQuery.support.opacity) {`

Comment: Out of curiosity, can't you use fadeIn() instead of animating the opacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an overflow property that doesn't appear to be getting set correctly.  Try ensuring that you have an `overflow: hidden;` declaration for your div element.